# Saving Arm Trajectory and Replaying it

Tags: ros, jointtrajectory, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

How can I save PR2 arm trajectory and then replay the same trajectory at a later time?
One way I can think of it is by writing trajectory_msg::JointTrajectory to a file and then reading the trajectory from the file whenever I need to reproduce the trajectory. But if I follow this method then I am not sure how to save "duration time_to_start" (which have many attributes) and "Header header".

Does anyone knows of any neater way for saving/replaying trajectories?

Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56823/saving-arm-trajectory-and-replaying-it/) by [Ashesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4149/ashesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosRos](https://answers.ros.org/users/4422/rosros/) on 2013-03-14**:
How can i write trajectory_msg::JointTrajectory to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ashesh

Apart from using stdio.h to write code to read a file of strings formatted like trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory. You could try writing [rostopic](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine) messages to your node. Or write your own [YAML](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosparam) file that contains the information about your trajectory and upload it to the parameter server. Then using a node to read the parameter server and format a JointTrajectory msgs from the information and publishing it.

As for converting an integer or float to a duration type you can save your duration as a float or integer and [use](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Time):

```
ros::Duration(24*60*60);
```

with the time in seconds in the brackets. And your stamp values in your header you just use:

```
header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
```

before you publish it.

hope it helps

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1